# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cors

i am trying to call a service through javascript and getting the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://www.somthing.com/something.svc. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.somthing.com' is therefore not allowed access.

We also tried jsonp , but that not works!

We have tried setting cors certificate as below, but no joy

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"},
        url: '//sharedservices.qa-worldventures.biz/MembershipService.svc/Subscriptions?source=DreamTrips&group=Perks&Locale=en-US',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: onSuccessGetSubscriptionsId
    });
```

Could you please hop in?

Comment: You need to read up on HTTP access control (CORS), eg. on MND: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: _“We have tried setting cors certificate as below, but no joy”_ – you have not understood how CORS works. The remote party is the one that has to allow the connection.

Comment: but the service is working with another website , hence issue is with local site not remote

Comment: Yes the reason the service might be working with another website is that in the CORS configuration you the service definitely would have specified access from certain URL's,/ paths and not "*".

Comment: They have given * access, so what is the other issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like **Cross Origin** problem, the server you are sending request doesn't allow that type of header you are requesting thats why you get a *pre-flight* response.

> If you have access on the server. Try enabling Cross Origin support.

In **Apache** adding `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" )`

You can check how to enable cross origin here.  [CORS Origin](https://enable-cors.org/server.html).

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: its already there in script right?  headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"},  is there any difference what you are talking about?

Comment: It should be on the server. Not the client that will send the request. So that the server will know if this is allowed on the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: server i don't have access, let assume, its there, any other issues?